# eventListener for hashChange

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, hashchange

I am trying to add an event listener for my page in ReactJS. I have added it to componentDidMount(). But the is only triggered for the initial page load.

How can I get it trigger whenever there is a change in the address bar.

```
componentDidMount:function(){

        window.addEventListener("hashchange", console.log('hashchange1'));
        $(window).bind("hashchange", console.log('$ - hashchange'));
        window.onhashchange =  console.log('hashchange3');      
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('hashChange',console.log('ReactDOM - hashchange'));
    },
```

I've tried several different ways to get it to work, but they all work only on the first load. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just executing the `console.log` in every case, and adding its return value as the listener. You need to pass a function as an event listener, for example:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", e => console.log('hashchange1', window.location.hash ));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ku6okrp2/

EDIT to make it look more obvious using ES5:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){ 
  console.log('hashchange1', window.location.hash )
});
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't understand it correctly. Thought the function (console.log) would be called nonetheless, but I guess it needs an event. Thanks.

Comment: @fractal5 Well you can pass `console.log` as event listener, just like any other function, if you don't execute it: `window.addEventListener("hashchange",  console.log );` https://jsfiddle.net/ku6okrp2/1/